# atomic set bits in array of bytes

Tags: c, multithreading, locking, atomic, compare-and-swap

How do you atomically set bits of a byte? The problem I am trying to solve concerns updating a huge array of bytes, say uchar data[262144]. I am setting only 2 bits of a byte at one time using SET(index,value), which means four threads could be setting values in one byte simultaneously. It is very rare that threads select the same byte to update but it does happen. What is the most efficient way to make these operations thread safe? Note that I can't use a lock per data entry which would be too big and too slow.

To make matters worse, sometimes another array of bytes, data1[131072], needs to  be updated simultaneously with the previous data in a thread safe way too. But I am planning to merge these two arrays to simplify the problem so an atomic way of updating the first array is enough.

Comment: Would it be feasible to, say, maintain a separate copy of the data per-thread, and then merge at the end?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Most of the time the threads access data in their partition but they do access and update other partitions as well.

Comment: If "other partition" updates are only occasional, how about requesting the owner thread to do the update?  That could have low amortized cost.

Comment: Yes I thought about exploiting that locality, which I will do as a last resort.

Comment: Or you could use one lock per partition, no? In general you can reduce lock contention in arrays of objects by hashing the object index and using the hash to choose a lock; that allows you to tune, even dynamically, the number of locks.

Comment: Indeed I will try the lock approach since it is simple and allows me to update data1 as well. I guess I can divide the data in to several 'banks' and improve performance instead of just using 1 partition per thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use CompareExchange primitive. What exactly you need to write, depends on the compiler and the platform. However, in theory, it looks like the following.

Assume CompareExchange returns oldvalue and atomically changes value only if oldvalue is not changed.

```
    do {
        oldvalue = bitset;
        newvalue = oldvalue|bitvalue;
    } while ( oldvalue != CompareExchange(&bitset,newvalue,oldvalue) );
```

Since CompareExchange is atomic, it will set bits atomically. But you can set bits atomically only in maximum one processor word sized bitset.